# Creating spatial index (PostGIS vs MySQL)

Tags: mysql, postgis

Is it possible to create index in MySQL similar to this one (PostGIS):

```
CREATE INDEX spatial_indx_test ON spatial_test USING gist(st_makeline(st_makepoint(x1,y1), st_makepoint(x2,y2)));
```

where x1,x2,y1,y2 are double-typed numbers stored in the table: spatial_test. Basically is there a way to make index on data that is not directly a column in a table? I've tried smth like this:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX spatial_indx_test ON spatial_test (LineString(Point(x1,y1), Point(x2,y2));
```

however it doesn't work in MySQL. Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create spation index on the geometry  eg:

> CREATE TABLE geom (g GEOMETRY NOT NULL, SPATIAL INDEX(g))
>   ENGINE=MyISAM;

you can find more  here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html  and here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yeah, MySQL lets me create index on specific column, however in my table there aren't any columns with spatial data. That date is created in queries. In PostGIS it is possible to make index on: `(st_makeline(st_makepoint(x1,y1), st_makepoint(x2,y2)))` where x1,x2, y1, y2 are fields from table nad are not spatial. So in short, in the table i have normal data (coordinates of points) and in queries i make spatial data from them (LineString) and i want to make index on that data. Is it possible anyhow in MySQL or i should make another table with those lines and then make index?

Comment: if you are using postgis or mysql spatial extensions why on earth save x,y in separate columns??